# sequelize Nested include with where clause

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize for some filtering.

My current table structure:

- Table1 holds Items (which has images) and Users (irrelevant)
- Table1 has a direct relationship to Table2 through Table2id on Table1 (not to Table3)
- Table2 has a direct relationship to Table3 through Table3id on Table2 (not to Table4)
- Table3 has a direct relationship to Table4 through Table4id on Table3

I want to filter on Table3 and Table4 as well, considering I can only filter on Table2 using the top-level where-clause.

The way I fill out my where condition is just using a base object:

```
var Table2id       = parseInt(req.query.Table2id) || null,
    Table3id       = parseInt(req.query.Table3id) || null,
    Table4id       = parseInt(req.query.Table4id) || null,
    whereCondition = { deleted: 0 }

if (Table2id) { whereCondition['table2id'] = Table2id }
if (Table3id) { whereCondition['table3id'] = Table3id }
if (Table4id) { whereCondition['table4id'] = Table4id }

Table1.findAndCountAll({
        limit: limit,
        offset: offset,
        order: 'created_at DESC',
        where: whereCondition,
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
            }, {
                model: Item,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Image
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                model: Table2,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Table3,
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: Table4,
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
}).then(function (results) { res.json(results) })
```

I tried using some hacks I discovered like `whereCondition['$Table3.table3id$'] = Table3id` but to no avail.

How can I filter on nested includes? Is there another way I can structure the query so I don't have to have nested includes, but still retain this data structure (is there even a better way to structure this than what I've thought of)?

edit: So I would like to both be able to sort on the tables included, and have at least one parameter set in the top-level where-clause (like deleted = 0).

I've tried modifying the query as follows:

```
var Table2id       = parseInt(req.query.Table2id) || null,
    Table3id       = parseInt(req.query.Table3id) || null,
    Table4id       = parseInt(req.query.Table4id) || null,
    whereCondition = { deleted: 0 },
    extraWhereCondition = {}

if (Table2id) { whereCondition['table2id'] = Table2id } // figured this can be left alone in this particular case (as it works in top-level where clause)
if (Table3id) { extraWhereCondition['table3id'] = Table3id }
if (Table4id) { extraWhereCondition['table4id'] = Table4id }

Table1.findAndCountAll({
        limit: limit,
        offset: offset,
        order: 'created_at DESC',
        where: whereCondition,
        include: [
            {
                model: User,
            }, {
                model: Item,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Image
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                model: Table2,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Table3,
                        where: extraWhereCondition,
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: Table4,
                                where: extraWhereCondition,
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
}).then(function (results) { res.json(results) })
```

But this gives me an error that Table2.Table3.Table4.table4id is unknown in field list.

Comment: you can put where clause in each include

Comment: @Adiii That gives me an `unknown column 'Table2.Table3.Table4.Table4id' in field list` error.

Comment: what do you need? actually, i did not get your question if u need where clause in inner include then let me know

Comment: var user = require('../models/').table1;
var user = require('../models/').table2;
include: [{
                                     model: table1, required: true,
                                     include: [
                                         {
                                             model: table2, required: true,
where:{condtion}
                                         }
                                     ]
                                 }]

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading

Comment: All the models are included, couldn't find anything related to my question in the docs which is why I've taken to SO.

Comment: but the way you putting where in inner include​ its not valid according to doc

Comment: Thanks, you're completely correct. Sorry... I followed your direction and also changed the way I assigned the where clauses (by looking through the code a little closer). Completely missed out on my own train of thought...

Comment: can i post that to accept as a answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, man, of course. I'll happily give you points :D

Comment: hehe okay check it this will help you to make option then use in your class

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You just need to the way to put `where` and you can also make option object and then pass it where you need

- put `where condition` in every `include` if need
- `required true and false` change joing rule

> When an eager loaded model is filtered using include.where then
> include.required is implicitly set to true. This means that an inner
> join is done returning parent models with any matching children.

- sequelize called it `eager-loading` visit for more detail [eager-loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#eager-loading)

```js
var Table2 = require("../models/").table2; //and other model that u need

var option = {
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
  order: "created_at DESC",
  where: { deleted: 0 },
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
    },
    {
      model: Item,
      required: true,

      include: [
        {
          model: Image,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      model: Table2,
      include: [
        {
          model: Table3,
          where: { deleted: 0 },
          include: [
            {
              model: Table4,
              where: { deleted: 0 },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

Table1.findAndCountAll(option).then(function (results) {
  res.json(results);
});
```